# how can pause audio url in flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio

I learn how to play an audio url in flutter :

```
FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {

            final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

            try {
              await assetsAudioPlayer.open(
                Audio.network("https://www.qurantranslations.net/sound/Portuguese/Saad_Al-Ghamdi/001.mp3"),
              );
            } catch (t) {

            }

          },
          child: Text('play'),
        ),
```

but how to create another button and to pause it, assets_audio_player: ^2.0.3+2  I'm using: https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player/versions/2.0.3+2
I'm tired a lot times but without success, please help me.

Comment: use `assetsAudioPlayer .playOrPause();` and check the [assets_audio_player example](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player/versions/2.0.3+2/example) again

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions on the onTap of play-=pause button to control audio

assetsAudioPlayer.playOrPause();

assetsAudioPlayer.play();

assetsAudioPlayer.pause();

Comment: hi Nikhil if you have free time please can give a example, I'm beginner